# Issue with Flutter Dio package

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dio

I'm using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package to retrieve data from my database(php and mySQL).

The application was working fine for more than 1 year after I upgrade **Flutter** for some reason I'm now getting this error:

```
DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104
```

How can I solve this ?

**Flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale fr-BF)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Please include the details with Flutter doctor log.

Comment: Which version of the Dio package are you using?